# Google top 1000

Tags: discussion, seo, traffic

Is stackoverflow in [google's top 1000](http://www.google.com/adplanner/static/top1000/#) most visited websites yet ?

Comment: 824     stackoverflow.com   Music - LoL!

Comment: And it's mentioned with no advertising. Which I guess is a sign it is nicely implemented... or they just haven't checked.

Comment: Note that dropbox is under the "Myth and Folklore" category, near the end

Comment: Detailed info: https://www.google.com/adplanner/planning/site_profile#siteDetails?identifier=stackoverflow.com

Comment: "878  stackoverflow.com Programming 6,200,000 0.4% 51,000,000 Yes"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, #824, category 'music' :)

Comment: because of the question - [Music to listen to while coding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947)? :D

Answer (score 1):

> Has Ads = No

Huh?

Comment: Well, it doesn't have *Google* ads, so they must not count. ;)

Comment: @Bill So that means msn.com & microsoft.com use Google ads :D